# Clustering images based on low/mid level features

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I wish to cluster images based on some basic low-level visual features (e.g. mean hue, brightness, etc) and mid-level features such as how much a certain images is circular / abstract vs concrete / contains many shapes / etc.

What are some additional features I can use? What will be the best strategy to perform this kind of features extraction?

Comment: Mid level features need neural network. Please add more detail to your question

Comment: @qwr Ok so I will start with low level features - what are the best ones?